# Outer Join with plus (+) in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join

I have some tables in Oracle.

**Table_1 contains :**

```
id|name
1|boy
2|roy
```

**Table_2 contains :**

```
id|value
1|90
2|100
```

**Table_3 contains :**

```
id|class
1|A
2|B
```

I want to join all three tables.

**Query_1 :**

```
SELECT A.ID,A.NAME,B.VALUE,C.CLASS 
FROM 
TABLE_1 A, TABLE_2 B, TABLE_3 C
WHERE 
A.ID=B.ID(+) AND
B.ID=C.ID(+)
```

OR

**Query_2 :**

```
SELECT A.ID,A.NAME,B.VALUE,C.CLASS 
FROM 
TABLE_1 A, TABLE_2 B, TABLE_3 C
WHERE 
A.ID=B.ID(+) AND
A.ID=C.ID(+)
```

Which one is true?

Comment: Why don't you try ? Anyway, as you have the same ids in all 3 tables, an inner join would work fine as well.

Comment: Stop using (+). 1) It is not ANSI complaint 2) May be hard to read 3) You have great `OUTER JOIN` clause in SQL Standard

Comment: @X.L.Ant : I have tried both of them and succeed. but I'm not sure what i did was right  :)

Comment: Of course both work, because all the ids are present everywhere. Why not do a simple inner join ? But as said by @lad2025, whatever you choose, use the ANSI compliant clauses (inner join, left outer join...)

Comment: @lad2025 : I will try :)

Comment: Even Oracle recommends to use a proper JOIN operator for outer joins, so forget about the `(+)`

Answer (score 0):

When you need an Outer Join:
Your query will include two or more tables where there may not exist a match for every record.  Examples will explain best.  If you have two tables: "Parent", and "Work".  If you want to ask the question:  What contacts do we have within our parent list within local employers an inner join works fine:

```
    select w.employer, w.phone, w.address,p.name, p.phone
    from work w, parent p
    where w.person_id = p.person_id
```

If the question is where do our parents work -- well some may be unemployed and have no match in the "work" table  -- now you need an outer join.  in Oracle SQL:

```
    select p.name, p.phone, w.employer, w.phone, w.address,
    from work w, parent p
    where p.person_id =  w.person_id(+)
```

The (+) always goes on the side where we need to "synthetically" add a missing id.